# Drawing a pyglet batch increases memory usage?

Tags: python, animation, opengl, memory, pyglet

I'm trying to use Pyglet's batch drawing capabilities to speed up the rendering of an animation which mainly consists of drawing a large set of vertices many times per second using `GL_LINES`. Speed-wise, I succeeded, as previously laggy animations now run crisp up to 60 fps. However, I noticed that every time a new frame of animation is drawn (by calling `batch.draw()` on a few batches, within a function scheduled to be called every frame by `pyglet.clock.schedule_interval()`), the memory used by the program steadily rises.

I expect the memory usage to substantially increase while *creating* the batches (and it does), but I don't understand why a mere call to `batch.draw()` also seems to be causing it, or at least why the memory usage seems to accumulate over future frames. Do I need to somehow manually delete previously drawn images from memory each time I need to redraw a frame? If so, I've found nothing in the Pyglet documentation about needing to do such a thing.

In my program, I call `pyglet.gl.glClear(pyglet.gl.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)` at the beginning of each new frame update in order to clear the previous frame, but perhaps the previous frame is still persisting in memory?

---

Below is an independent example script which exhibits this precise behavior:

```
import pyglet as pg
import random

currentFrame = 0
window = pg.window.Window(600,600)

# A list of lists of batches to be drawn at each frame.
frames = []

# Make 200 frames...
for frameCount in range(200):
    batches = []
    for n in range(3):
        batch = pg.graphics.Batch()

        # Generate a random set of vertices within the window space
        batch.add(1000, pg.gl.GL_LINES, None,
            ("v2f", tuple(random.random()*600 for i in range(2000))),
            ("c3B", (255,255,255)*1000))
        batches.append(batch)
    frames.append(batches)

# This function will be called every time the window is redrawn
def update(dt, frames=frames):
    global currentFrame
    if currentFrame >= len(frames):
        pg.clock.unschedule(update)
        print("Animation complete")
        return

    batches = frames[currentFrame]

    # Clear the previous frame
    pg.gl.glClearColor(0,0,0,1)  # Black background color
    pg.gl.glClear(pg.gl.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)

    # Define line width for this frame and draw the batches
    pg.gl.glLineWidth(5)
    for batch in batches:
        batch.draw()

    currentFrame += 1

# Call the update() function 30 times per second.
pg.clock.schedule_interval(update, 1.0/30)
pg.app.run()
```

While the animation is running, no new batches should be created, and yet the memory used by Python steadily increases thruout the duration of the animation.

Comment: If you add the offending code to the question, people will have more to go on when trying to answer your question

Comment: @Gab. Understood. I was trying to avoid that since the code is quite large and potentially confusing. Nevertheless, I will try to add what I can.

Comment: In that case, I believe a [mcve] would be the right thing to add

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry that this might be an extremely late answer, but for anyone coming across this...

you have created 2 lists which are the source of the linear memory usage increase:

```
frames = []
```

and

```
batches = []
```

on lines 8 and 12 respectively.

Then, in your for loop you add 3 batches into the "batches" list and then add those into the "frames" list.

```
for frameCount in range(200):
    batches = []
    for n in range(3):
        batch = pg.graphics.Batch()

        # Generate a random set of vertices within the window space
        batch.add(1000, pg.gl.GL_LINES, None,
            ("v2f", tuple(random.random()*600 for i in range(2000))),
            ("c3B", (255,255,255)*1000))
        batches.append(batch)
    frames.append(batches)
```

fortunately, you do override whatever is in "batches" in here:

```
batches = frames[currentFrame]
```

but that still leaves out "frames", which is never reset and for every frame, has 3 more batches in it.

if you start with 0 frames and end with 200 frames, your memory usage with this "frames" list will go from storing nothing to storing 600 batches.

try to reset the "frames" lst after each frame and keeping track of your count of frames with a simple integer.

I hope this helps at least someone